# How I get the string between CONTENT 2 Apostrophes

Tags: c#

How do I get the string between CONTENT 2 Apostrophes, in this case abc

```
string s ="<meta NAME=\"og:title\" CONTENT=\"abc\">";
```

Comment: Well, you have two strings between Apostrophes, `og:title` and `abc`.

Comment: CONTENT 2 Apostrophes

Comment: Now it is more clear after your edit.

Comment: you are looking for regex code

Comment: whatever you have

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use:

```
var s ="<meta NAME=\"og:title\" CONTENT=\"abc\">";
var match = Regex.Match(s, "CONTENT=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // abc
}
```

You can skip the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` part in case the casing of your input string (especially CONTENT) is always the same.